RefreshEvent doesn't refresh relatedList
I have a quick action for creating an Opportunity from an Account. The quick action is an LWC component, and upon submitting the button, I need to refresh the Opportunity related list on the Account.
However, the RefreshEvent is not working for that.
Parent HTML:



        <div class="slds-media__body slds-card__header-title slds-text-title_bold slds-align_absolute-center" style="font-size: 16px;text-align:center;">
            Create Pharmacy Opportunity 
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <lightning-record-edit-form 
            object-api-name="Opportunity"
            onsubmit={handleSubmit}
            onsuccess={handleSuccess}
            onerror={handleError}
            record-type-id="012Dp000000YKOZ">
            
            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>

            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <lightning-combobox
                        name="progress"
                        label="Name"
                        value={selectedValue}
                        options={options}
                        onchange={handleChange} >
                    </lightning-combobox>

                    
                    <lightning-input label="Custom Name" type="name" if:true={showNameInput}></lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Amount" type="number"></lightning-input-field>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="CloseDate" type="date" required value={defaultClosedDate}></lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="StageName" required value="Clicked In"></lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Name" value={name} class="slds-hidden"></lightning-input-field>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
<lightning-card >
    <c-lwc-dynamic-record-rows-creation oncloseandrefresh={handleCloseAndRefresh}></c-lwc-dynamic-record-rows-creation>
</lightning-card>

Parent JS:
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';
import { RefreshEvent } from 'lightning/refresh';

import NAME_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Name";
const fields = [NAME_FIELD];

export default class CreateOpportunity extends LightningElement {
handleCloseAndRefresh(event){
        console.log('>>> Inside parent handle... ');
        this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
        //this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
        
    }
}

Event Fired from Child:
this.dispatchEvent(
                    new CustomEvent("closeandrefresh", {
                                        detail: "ball"
                                    })
                    );

